# C# Winforms application opens from Command Prompt and in debugger, but not from File Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I programmed this C# Winforms app to open when a file is clicked on in the File Explorer (from the "Open with..." command). However, instead of opening, the app simply crashes without an error message. From the Task Manager, the app can be seen running briefly before disappearing.

From a test app, I was able to find out that the File Explorer sends a file path as the first argument. Starting the app from a debugger or from the Command Prompt works (even with a file path as an argument).

Here's the code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        MainForm form = new MainForm();

        if (args.Length > 0) {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(args[0])) {
                form.OpenFile_(args[0]);
            }
        }

        try {
            Application.Run(form);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            form = new MainForm();
            form.SetStatus("Something went wrong opening the file.");
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
```

Even with the try/catch block, the app fails to start from the File Explorer. *It works without any problems from the Command Prompt or in a debugger.*

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` on the first line of the Main method and start your app from Open with. Also check event viewer for exceptions.

Comment: Run `eventvwr.msc` and have a look at the Application events; you will probably find the exception causing your program to die there.

Comment: You should also attach event handlers to the `Application.ThreadException` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` events to show a message box with the exception details. You may also use the `Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode`method to our needs.

Comment: I use something like: (Program.cs) `if (args.Length > 0) { Application.Run(new MyMainForm(args)); } else { Application.Run(new MyMainForm()); }`. In the starting Form: `public MyMainForm() : this(null) { }` and  `public MyMainForm(string[] args) { //Processing }`. In the Registry, `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, in the file extension section (`.something`), (Default) REG_SZ "MyAppID.Version". In `MyAppID.Version`: (Default) REG_SZ [File Type Description], shell/open/command "[Path]\executable.exe" -open "%1" %*. All error handling is performed in `MyMainForm`, while inspecting the `args[]` content.

Comment: That try is placed incorrectly, it cannot catch MainForm.OpenFile() failing.  In fact it cannot catch anything at all, it only seems to when you use a debugger.  Writing an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException is never really optional.

Comment: The way it works was this:
I had a config file that I referred to as "settings.txt" (the file is in the same folder as the app).
This means that when the app tries to run, it looks first looks for "settings.txt" in the current folder.
In the command line or in a debugger, it's not a problem, since it executes with the current folder as the one with the app (and therefore the settings file).
However, with the "Open with..." command, the current file path is _from where "Open with..." is called_, and there's no "settings.txt" there. The app dies with a `FileNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, really:

Instead of:

```
string SettingsFilePath = "settings.txt";
```

Use:

```
string SettingsFilePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\settings.txt";
```